# db2 clpplus whenever sqlerror exit

Tags: db2, whenever

a short question. I want to create a litte DB2 CLPLUS script which exits if a sqlerror occurs and does a rollback. The problem is if you use WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT also the CLPPLUS session exits. But this is not what i want. Only the script should be aborted nothing else. 
Remark: The scripts includes two or more sql statements. After the first sql statements generates an error the script should be exit and the other statements should not run.

Kind regards
Ralf

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to catch the exception, and then to temporarily continue and process that exception including performing a (conditional) rollback and subsequently exit, then you should use `WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE ...` followed by the block that includes your exception handler.

If you use `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT` then the documented behaviour for clpplus is  to exit back to the operating-system. When you don't want that behaviour then use `WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE...` instead.

Remember that some SQLCODES have an implicit rollback performed already by Db2 (e.g. -911 and related) so you may need to filter the exception SQLCODE.

For some specific suggestions, you should edit your question to include your code *AND* the expected behaviour in a minimal verifiable example.